# Is there a way to define browser args using Selenide?

Tags: kotlin, testing, browser-automation, selenide

I am trying to do the same test but with selenide instead of selenium.
The web site i am testing requires these 4 arguments otherwise won't work.

Is there a way to define browser args using Selenide?

```
    private val driver = ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions()
        .addArguments("--disable-blink-features")
        .addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        .addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        .addArguments("--no-sandbox")
    )
```

**Tried both ways but it seems the args are ignored.**

**command line:**

```
./gradlew test -Dchromeoptions.args=--diagnostics,--disable-blink-features,-disable-gpu,--start-maximized,--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled,--disable-dev-shm-usage,--no-sandbox
```

**kotlin. Tested inside a @BeforeAll - JUnit5**

```
val desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities()
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(
   ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,
   ChromeOptions()
      .addArguments("--disable-gpu")
      .addArguments("--start-maximized")
      .addArguments("--disable-blink-features")
      .addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
      .addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
      .addArguments("--no-sandbox")
)
desiredCapabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true)
Configuration.browserCapabilities = desiredCapabilities
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Either via command line:

```
-Dchromeoptions.args=--diagnostics,--disable-blink-features
```

or in java code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen", "--start-incognito");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", ImmutableMap.of("intl.accept_languages", "de_DE"));
Configuration.browserCapabilities = options;
open("https://codeborne.com";)
```

See https://selenide.org/2017/01/26/selenide-4.2.1/

Comment: I edited the body of the question with what i used. I tried both ways but they don't seem to work. It ignores the arguments.

Comment: yes it doesn't work. I also tried it. It completely ignores the arguments passed.